# Solving underdetermined linear equations over the nonnegative integers

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-diophantine-equations

I want to prove the following:

Let $j_1, \ldots, j_8 \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$.
If
\begin{align*}
 j_1 + j_2 + 2 j_3 - j_4 - j_6 -2 j_8 &= 0 \\
 -j_1 + j_2 + j_4 + 2j_5 - j_6 -2 j_7 &=0
\end{align*}
show that there exist $i_1, \ldots, i_{12} \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ such that
\begin{align*}
 j_1 &= i_1 + i_5 + i_6 + 2 i_9 \\
 j_2 &= i_2 + i_6 + i_7 + 2 i_{10} \\
 j_3 &= i_3 + i_8 + i_{11} + i_{12} \\
 j_4 &= i_1 + i_7 + i_8 + 2 i_{12} \\
 j_5 &= i_4 + i_5 + i_9 + i_{11} \\
 j_6 &= i_2 + i_5 + i_8 + 2 i_{11} \\
 j_7 &= i_4 + i_7 + i_{10} + i_{12} \\
 j_8 &= i_3 + i_6 + i_9 + i_{10}
\end{align*}

This statement is the final step in a wider proof of a fact that I believe is true, so I'm hoping for a proof rather than a counterexample.

The problem is trivial if there are no restrictions on each $i_k$, but I'm struggling to solve it with the constraint that they are non-negative.
One can reduce the second system to reduced row echelon form, though it's not clear how to choose each unconstrained variable to ensure all the $i_k$ are non-negative.

I would appreciate if someone knows how to solve the problem, or a reference to learn about techniques which may be useful.
I believe [Farkas' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) may be of assistance, though I'm unsure of how to apply it here.

Comment: From the Gaussian elimination one can see directly, say, that $i_1=j_1$, $i_2=j_6$, $i_3 = (j_1 + 2j_3 - j_4)/2$, $i_4=j_5$, $i_{10}= (j_2 - j_6)/2$, $i_{12} = ( - j_1 + j_4)/2$ works, with $i_k=0$ otherwise, provided that $j_4\ge j_1$ and $j_6\le j_2$. However, this is already a lot, because we might arrange this, or just study these cases separately.